# how can i useNavigate on a form in a class in jsx

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i'm trying to navigate from class component when clicked on a button in form to another component but i'm having a problem in using useNavigate as t's said it works only in function so i tried this code

```
import React from 'react';
import "./login.css"
import NavBar from './navbar';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends React.Component {
state ={
    username : "",
    password :"",
}


navigator=()=>{
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate('/contact');
}

render() { 
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {/*this is the NavBar */}
           <NavBar />
            {/*this is the form of sign in */}
            <main className="login-form-signin">
{/* here i call the use navigator function so that it works when i submit the form*/}
                <form onSubmit={()=>{navigator() }}>
                    <div className="login-upper-div">
                        <i className="fas fa-paw fa-2x"></i>
                        <h2 className="login-h2">Sign In</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-floating">
                        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com"/>
                        <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-floating">
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
                        <label htmlFor="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="checkbox mb-3">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"/> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button className="w-100 login-btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" >Sign in</button>
                    <div className="icon-div">
                        <i className="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
                        <i className="fab fa-google fa-2x"></i>    
                        <i className="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" ></i>
                        <i className="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
}
}
export  default Login;
```

and after running the code above it gives and error with that

```
      throw Error( "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:\n1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)\n2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks\n3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app\nSee https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem." );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks only into functional components.
For class components you can use hocs

Answer:

```
export default withRouter(Login);
```

And than you can access all from props:

```
const { match, location, history } = this.props;
history.push('/contact');
```

Comment: i'm using latest react dom 17.2 i think or something so the history is not available any more and replaced with navigate that's what made me work on navigate already

Comment: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7156

Comment: So looks like you should move to functional components. Or past navigation prop from parent. I don't have other ideas.